# YOLOv5 :: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.downloads'

Tags: python, yolov5

This error occurs when running YOLOv5 in Flask after setting up a virtual environment.

```
(venv) bash-3.2$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gyeongdeokpark/Desktop/Electricity_meter-main/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/gyeongdeokpark/Desktop/Electricity_meter-main/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from yolov5.models.experimental import attempt_load
  File "/Users/gyeongdeokpark/Desktop/Electricity_meter-main/yolov5/models/experimental.py", line 11, in <module>
    from utils.downloads import attempt_download
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.downloads'
```

In order to resolve the above error, the following measures have been taken:

```
pip install requests
pip install utill
```

but these measures seem to not belong to the solution (I wonder if they were unnecessary steps).

And this is the structure of my project folder (please refer to it if you need to take measures regarding the file paths):
[image]

[image]

Comment: You installed ```utill` but used ```utils```?   What is this ```utils.downloads``` from?

Comment: utils.downloads location is Electricity_meter-main/yolov5/utils/downloads.py

Comment: Error is caused in experimental.py which is in the models folder. However, utils isn't in that folder but outside of models. Thus, it is not able to locate utils and hence unable to import from utils.downloads. Try moving the utils file in the models folder once and run it.